# Error with redirection of website with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I was trying to get rid of the index.html in my url.

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://saturnstudios.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Everytime I load the website https://www.saturnstudios.org/index I get the error  Error 404 - Not Found
The document you are looking for may have been removed or re-named. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

Even though the documents are named right.

[image]

```
<h1 class="nav-link"><a href="index">Home</a></h1>
</li>
<li>
   <h1 class="nav-link"><a href="about">About</a></h1>
</li>
<li>
<h1 class="nav-link"><a href="contact">Contact</a></h1>
```

Any ideas of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [remove `.html` extension from **url**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026967/3286975) with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]
```

Add it on the end.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `MultiViews` option to make it work by loading correct file after adding extensions internally.

Place this line at top of your .htacces:

```
Options +MultiViews
```